# AWS EC2 Xcache or APC

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apc, amazon-ec2, xcache

I am working on AWS EC2 Ubuntu machine and I am not able to enable `xcache` and `APC` simultaneously. Whenever I enable `xcache` , `APC` will get disable and vice versa.

[image]

So my question is, How can I enable both of them?

Comment: This may be dated information, but the two packages appear to be incompatible on some level, so they are flagged as conflicting so they can't be installed together: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=614687